# jQuery sort different class elements by attribute

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, custom-data-attribute

There is two arrays that display information appending elements to the document. They are being printed in ascending order, but when it comes to organize them all, I can't organize them individually by data attribute.

This function does the sort but can't mix different element classes:

```
        $.fn.sortRaffles = function () {
          this
            .children()
            .sort((a, b) => $(a).data("order") - $(b).data("order") || -1)
            .appendTo(this);

          return this;
        }
        $(".lista ul").sortRaffles();
```

Before the above code this is where I print the two different element classes (avaibleRaffle and reservedRaffle) using arrays of string and filtering them to display the correct result.

```
const nums = Array.from({ length: 11 }, (_, i) => `${i}`.padStart(3, "0"));

const customers = [
  { number: "002" },
  { number: "6003" },
  { number: "1010" },
  { number: "008,005,007,0002" }
];

const reserved_nums = nums.filter(
  (s) => !customers.some((o) => o.number.includes(s))
);

const avaible_nums = nums.filter((s) =>
  customers.some((o) => o.number.includes(s))
);

var avaibleRaffle = $();
$.each(avaible_nums, function (index, value) {
  avaibleRaffle = avaibleRaffle.add(
    '<span class="btn btn-success btn_reservas data-order="' +
      value +
      '" >' +
      value +
      "</span>"
  );
});
$(".lista ul li").append(avaibleRaffle);

var reservedRaffle = $();
$.each(reserved_nums, function (index, value) {
  reservedRaffle = reservedRaffle.add(
    '<span class="btn btn-warning btn_pagos data-order="' +
      value +
      '" >' +
      value +
      "</span>"
  );
});
$(".lista ul li").append(reservedRaffle);
```

The a minimal reproducible example:

```js
/* eslint-env jquery */

const nums = Array.from({ length: 11 }, (_, i) => `${i}`.padStart(3, "0"));

const customers = [
  { number: "002" },
  { number: "6003" },
  { number: "1010" },
  { number: "008,005,007,0002" }
];

const reserved_nums = nums.filter(
  (s) => !customers.some((o) => o.number.includes(s))
);

const avaible_nums = nums.filter((s) =>
  customers.some((o) => o.number.includes(s))
);

var avaibleRaffle = $();
$.each(avaible_nums, function (index, value) {
  avaibleRaffle = avaibleRaffle.add(
    '<span class="btn btn-success btn_reservas data-order="' +
      value +
      '" >' +
      value +
      "</span>"
  );
});
$(".lista ul li").append(avaibleRaffle);

var reservedRaffle = $();
$.each(reserved_nums, function (index, value) {
  reservedRaffle = reservedRaffle.add(
    '<span class="btn btn-warning btn_pagos data-order="' +
      value +
      '" >' +
      value +
      "</span>"
  );
});
$(".lista ul li").append(reservedRaffle);

$.fn.sortRaffles = function () {
  this.children()
    .sort((a, b) => $(a).data("order") - $(b).data("order") || -1)
    .appendTo(this);

  return this;
};
$(".lista ul li span").sortRaffles();

console.log("Desired Order:", JSON.stringify(nums));
console.log("Avaible:", JSON.stringify(avaible_nums));
console.log("Reserved:", JSON.stringify(reserved_nums));
```

```css
.lista ul li {
  display: inline;
}

.lista ul li span {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 40px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link
      type="text/css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.1/semantic.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="lista">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <span></span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve] (sample input, expected output, the rules how that output was generated) _in the question itself_.

Comment: Why an empty jQuery object (`var avaibleRaffle = $();`) instead of a simple array?

Comment: @Andreas I updated the post to make a cleaner code. Used this var to create a variable that will receive the specific array and use it to print the element, should I use only the array? This solution should further print more information besides the number (like a name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't resolve this problem of printing in ascending order the numbers after validating it with sort. Besides the collaboration,  I came with a solution that is only using forEach for comparison of arrays:

```
                nums.forEach(function (value) {
                    if (avaibleNumbers.indexOf(value) != -1) {
                        var av = avaibleNumbers.indexOf(value);
                        console.log(avaibleNumbers[av]);
                    }
                    else if (reservedNumbers.indexOf(value) != -1) {
                        var rs = reservedNumbers.indexOf(value);
                        console.log(reservedNumbers[rs]);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you should do to get your code working.
1- fix the html. You missed a `"` in both these line:

```
'<span class="btn btn-success btn_reservas**"** data-order="' +
```

Without it the browsers cannot read the `data-order` attribute.

2- Your sort function looks almost ok, but to make it work, do this:

```
$.fn.sortRaffles = function () {
    var ordered = $(this).sort(function(a,b){
        return parseInt(a.dataset.order,10) > parseInt(b.dataset.order, 10);
    });
    $(".lista ul li").html(ordered);
    return this;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, just fixed example html, but this function is presenting a problem "Missing radix parameter". I checked that is possible to use it only with string, but looks like a.dataset.order isn't enough to  use parseInt. Do you know what I'm missing?

Comment: Using any radix solves that. I updated the answer with 10 as radix.

Comment: It fixed, unfortunately elements still being printed aside, one class and then another, but not both according data-order attribute.